# How to write a script that can deal with input in the format of ARGF as well as file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

Is there a concise way to do it?

case 1

```
File.open(infile, 'r').readlines.each do |line|
  process
end
```

case 2

```
ARGF.readlines.each do |line|
  process
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
method = something_to_help_me_decide ? File.open(infile, 'r') : ARGF
method.readlines.each do |line|
  process
end
```

Not super clear what you're going for here.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted to get.